# HDFS free space available command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a hdfs command to see available free space in hdfs. We can see that through browser at master:hdfsport in browser , but for some reason I can't access this and I need some command.
I can see my disk usage through command ./bin/hadoop fs -du -h but cannot see free space available.

Thanks for answer in advance.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try this:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

With older versions of Hadoop, try this:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Comment: you can try this also "hadoop fs -df -h"

Comment: What is dfs used ? and what is non-dfs used ?

Comment: dfs used - space used by hdfs, non-dfs used - disk usage outside of hdfs.

Answer (score 16):

#### Methods

**1. dfsadmin**

In newer versions of HDFS the hadoop CLI for dfsadmin is deprecated:

```
$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -report
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.
```

So you should be using only `hdfs` at this point. Additionally when on systems where `sudo` is required you run it like so:

```
$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

**2. fs -df**

You have an additional method available via the `fs` module to `hadoop` as well:

```
$ hadoop fs -df -h
```

#### Example output

**dfsadmin**

Also to provide a more thorough answer here's what the output would look like from a single node installation.

```
$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 7504658432 (6.99 GB)
Present Capacity: 527142912 (502.72 MB)
DFS Remaining: 36921344 (35.21 MB)
DFS Used: 490221568 (467.51 MB)
DFS Used%: 93.00%
Under replicated blocks: 128
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 192.168.114.48:50010 (host-192-168-114-48.td.local)
Hostname: host-192-168-114-48.td.local
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 7504658432 (6.99 GB)
DFS Used: 490221568 (467.51 MB)
Non DFS Used: 6977515520 (6.50 GB)
DFS Remaining: 36921344 (35.21 MB)
DFS Used%: 6.53%
DFS Remaining%: 0.49%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 2
Last contact: Thu Feb 04 13:35:04 EST 2016
```

In the above example, the HDFS HDD space has been 100% utilized.

**fs -df**

That same system with the `-df` subcommand from the `fs` module:

```
$ hadoop fs -df -h
Filesystem                                 Size     Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://host-192-168-114-48.td.local:8020  7.0 G  467.5 M     18.3 M    7%
```

Answer (score 3):

### Hadoop version 1:

```
hadoop fs -df -h
```

OR

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

---

### Hadoop version 2:

```
hdfs dfs -df -h
```

OR

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```